# nil object in NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have a NSDictionary from which I read some values in two different methods in my code, however only in one of the methods the value of the key is retrieved correctly whereas in the other method I always get nil.

This is the method that works:

```
-(void)drawDriver:(NSString*)driverId withPosition:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)position withRotation:(float)bearing isAvailable:(BOOL)isDriverAvailable{

    GMSMarker *driverMarker = [driversList objectForKey:driverId];
    if (driverMarker != nil) {
        // do some work
    }
}
```

and it's called from this other method:

```
- (void) socketIO:(SocketIO *)socket didReceiveMessage:(SocketIOPacket *)packet
{
    NSMutableDictionary *datos = (NSMutableDictionary*)packet.data;
    NSDictionary *driverId = datos[@"from"];
    NSString *id = [driverId objectForKey:@"id"];

    //gets other values

    NSLog(@"Socket message: driverId: %@, position %f,%f, isAvailable:%d", id, latitude, longitude, isDriverAvailable);

    //Call the first method
    [self drawDriver:id withPosition:position withRotation:bearing isAvailable:isDriverAvailable];

}
```

And this is the method that doesn't work (returns nil for driverMarker):

```
-(void)updateMapForTripWithDriver:(NSString *)driverId {

    GMSMarker *driverMarker = [driversList objectForKey:driverId];
    if (driverMarker != nil) {
        //do some work
    }
}
```

and this is called from here:

```
- (void)updateTripWithData:(NSDictionary *)data {

    //This NSDictionary comes from a notification
    NSString *newStatus = [[data objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"];

    if ([newStatus isEqualToString:NO_TRIP]) {

    } else if ([newStatus isEqualToString:WAITING_CONFIRMATION]) {

    } else if ([newStatus isEqualToString:DRIVER_ON_THE_WAY]) {

        //Get the driverId and call the other method
        NSString *driverId = [data objectForKey:@"driver_id"];
        [self updateMapForTripWithDriver:driverId];
    }
}
```

As you can see both methods have the exact same code to retrieve the object but still I get different results.
The only difference I could find is when I put some breakpoints on the methods and this is what I found:

On the first method, although I pass the driverId as a NSString, somehow it's read as NSFCNumber and that seems to work because I get the value with no problems.

[image: These are the values on the first method]

But on the second method the key is read as an actual NSString which for some reason makes the method to return nil for an object that does exists on the NSDictionary.

[image]

How can I get the second method to work and return the right value?

Comment: Your debugging appears to indicate the problem: you're passing an `NSNumber` in one case, and a string in the other, and the key in the dictionary is actually a string. The code that generates the arguments and calls these methods is the culprit, so you'll need to show that if you want someone here to be able to help.

Comment: @JoshCaswell is correct, but i think the key is actually an `NSNumber`, not an `NSString`

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're right, @BradAllred: I got it backwards.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I just updated my question with the calls to both methods. How can I get the String to become a number and pass it to the dictionary as my key?